# python OOP class method retaining variable. Weird scoping thing

Tags: python, class, oop, dictionary, scope

I have two classes, a main class which creates instances of my other class.

```
class Builder:

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def build_thing(self, main_ftr, main_attr, attrs = {}):
        # note the main ftr/attrs gets added to attrs no matter what
        attrs[main_ftr] = attrs.get(main_ftr, []) + [main_attr]

        return Thing(main_ftr, main_attr, attrs)

class Thing:

    def __init__(self, main_ftr, main_attr, attrs):
        self.main_ftr = main_ftr
        self.main_attr = main_attr
        self.attrs = attrs
```

The issue I'm having has to do with the `attrs` dictionary that gets passed to the `Thing` class. The problem is that each time I use the `Builder` class to create a `Thing` class, the attrs argument retains it's previous values

```
b = Builder('123')

t = b.build_thing('name', 'john')
print(t.attrs) # {'name': ['john'] }

# Goal is this creates a new "Thing" with only attrs = {'name':['mike']}
t2 = b.build_thing('name', 'mike')
print(t2.attrs) # {'name': ['john', 'mike']}
```

My Question is 2 part:

Why is this happening?

How do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions' optional arguments are initialized once. Since `attrs` is mutable, each time you call the function, you add new key-value pair to this dictionary and it is kept for further calls. If you need a mutable data structure as a default parameter, use something like:

```
def build_thing(self, main_ftr, main_attr, attrs=None):
    if attrs is None:
        attrs = {}
    attrs[main_ftr] = attrs.get(main_ftr, []) + [main_attr]
    return Thing(main_ftr, main_attr, attrs)
```

Comment: Weird, just to clarify - this applies to any function that takes a default mutable argument (nothing to do with classes)? Therefore that function has that arg value tied to it for the life of the function/script?

Comment: @RSHAP Exactly!

Comment: @RSHAP For more scoping things check out: `funcs = [(lambda: x) for x in range(5)]` and `funcs = [(lambda x=x: x) for x in range(5)]` and see the difference between `for f in funcs: print(f())` with the two definitions...